# Android togglebutton doesn't display the correct value

Tags: android, togglebutton

I'm new in android development and I'm trying to add a `ToggleButton` to my first android project. and have a problem to make it work like I would like.

This is my `ToggleButton` :

```
<ToggleButton
   android:id="@+id/toggle1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:textOff="Off"
   android:textOn="On" />
```

And this is my Activity class :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_toggle);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }
     public void addListenerOnButton() {
         togglelocation = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle1);
         togglelocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                }
            });

          }
```

The problem is when I click on the toggle button nothing happens on the screen whereas I'm expecting that the toggle button toggle between on/off.

[image: togglebutton]

When I debugged, the value of `isChekced()` changes between True/False.

But on the screen level nothing changed. I don't know what I'm missing.

EDIT:

I think it's related to my device tablet huawei. I just test it in a virtual device and it work like a charm !!!!

Comment: //togglelocation.toggle(); you don want this line, if you are adding it. And the same code work fine for me

Comment: This code is working fine for me, Make sure that you commented   togglelocation.toggle(); before running code

Comment: togglelocation.toggle(); is not required at all it will automatically toggle the state. And you will get call to the click listener also.

Comment: yes togglelocation.toggle() is commented, I will remove it! but this is still not working for me ? I don't know what I'm missing perhaps something to do with my environement ??

Comment: I think it's related to my device tablet huawei. I just test it in a virtual device and it work like a charm !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any code to make it on/off. just add toggleButton to XML like this and it does what you need.:

```
 <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CreateFileButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />
```

to add some functionality use the below code in your Activity java file.

```
tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

    tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked)
            {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "on State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "off State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did. But not working for me!! any idea why ?

Comment: you are using setOnClicklistener(). and i am using setOnCheckedChangeListener(). both are different.

Comment: yes. is the toggle button enabled? check if you have set it to false in the xml or in the code somewhere. can you click it?

Comment: I think it's related to my device tablet huawei. I just test it in a virtual device and it work like a charm !!!!

Comment: Yes the toggle is enabled !

Comment: if its a device issue, then i can't help you. But, the solution works. I just checked it on my device. Hope my answer was helpful. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for you help ! it's either device issue or android version issue, anyway thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

In your activity class, move `togglelocation = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle1);` out of your `addListenerOnButton()` method, and put it inside `onCreate` method. Please put it before `addListenerOnButton()`, like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_toggle);

        togglelocation = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle1);

        addListenerOnButton();
    }
```

Comment: Hi ss1271, I edited my code see my question. but still have the same problem. even I click on the togglebutton nothing change. Sould I Update the screen or something like this ?